# Java web apps refuse to communicate with eachother while deployed on VPS tomcat server

Tags: java, spring, nginx, tomcat, vps

I have 2 problems that seem to be related to each other.

1. I have deployed 2 Java Spring Boot web apps (frontend Vaadin app and backend) on VPS linux based Tomcat server.
   Both of them work while testing in development environment (IntelliJ-provided Tomcat) and also when deploying to Tomcat server installed on my localhost manually.
   If I deploy my backend on my Tomcat VPS and try to communicate with it using Postman, it also works (I can use open endpoints without any issues).
   Same goes to front - it works by itself when accessing using VPS Tomcat interface.
   What doesn't work is when I deploy both my apps and make them communicate with eachother. It looks like there is some sort of timeout, but there is nothing in the catalina.out logs. Logs from the moment I'm trying to communicate with the backend in catalina.out (all have status 200):

> 2023-04-15 19:12:47.541 DEBUG 175 --- [io-20656-exec-9]
> o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST
> /?v-r=uidl&v-uiId=3 2023-04-15 19:12:47.542 DEBUG 175 ---
> [io-20656-exec-9] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set
> SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext 2023-04-15 19:12:47.542
> DEBUG 175 --- [io-20656-exec-9]
> o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder
> to anonymous SecurityContext 2023-04-15 19:12:47.542 DEBUG 175 ---
> [io-20656-exec-9] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    :
> Authorized filter invocation [POST /?v-r=uidl&v-uiId=3] with
> attributes [permitAll] 2023-04-15 19:12:47.542 DEBUG 175 ---
> [io-20656-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured
> POST /?v-r=uidl&v-uiId=3 2023-04-15 19:12:47.542 DEBUG 175 ---
> [io-20656-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST
> "/BeersAndMealsAppFrontendDebug/?v-r=uidl&v-uiId=3",
> parameters={masked} 2023-04-15 19:12:47.544 DEBUG 175 ---
> [io-20656-exec-9] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not
> store anonymous SecurityContext 2023-04-15 19:12:47.544 DEBUG 175 ---
> [io-20656-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed
> 200 OK 2023-04-15 19:12:47.544 DEBUG 175 --- [io-20656-exec-9]
> w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store anonymous
> SecurityContext 2023-04-15 19:12:47.544 DEBUG 175 ---
> [io-20656-exec-9] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared
> SecurityContextHolder to complete request 2023-04-15 19:12:47.651
> DEBUG 175 --- [o-20656-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy
> : Securing GET /create_account 2023-04-15 19:12:47.651 DEBUG 175 ---
> [o-20656-exec-10] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set
> SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext 2023-04-15 19:12:47.651
> DEBUG 175 --- [o-20656-exec-10]
> o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder
> to anonymous SecurityContext 2023-04-15 19:12:47.651 DEBUG 175 ---
> [o-20656-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    :
> Authorized filter invocation [GET /create_account] with attributes
> [permitAll] 2023-04-15 19:12:47.651 DEBUG 175 --- [o-20656-exec-10]
> o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /create_account
> 2023-04-15 19:12:47.651 DEBUG 175 --- [o-20656-exec-10]
> o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET
> "/BeersAndMealsAppFrontendDebug/create_account", parameters={}
> 2023-04-15 19:12:47.666 DEBUG 175 --- [o-20656-exec-10]
> w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store anonymous
> SecurityContext 2023-04-15 19:12:47.666 DEBUG 175 ---
> [o-20656-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed
> 200 OK 2023-04-15 19:12:47.666 DEBUG 175 --- [o-20656-exec-10]
> w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store anonymous
> SecurityContext 2023-04-15 19:12:47.666 DEBUG 175 ---
> [o-20656-exec-10] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared
> SecurityContextHolder to complete request 2023-04-15 19:12:47.894
> DEBUG 175 --- [io-20656-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy
> : Securing GET /?v-r=init&location=create_account&query= 2023-04-15
> 19:12:47.894 DEBUG 175 --- [io-20656-exec-3]
> s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder
> to empty SecurityContext 2023-04-15 19:12:47.894 DEBUG 175 ---
> [io-20656-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set
> SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext 2023-04-15
> 19:12:47.896 DEBUG 175 --- [io-20656-exec-3]
> o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorized filter
> invocation [GET /?v-r=init&location=create_account&query=] with
> attributes [permitAll] 2023-04-15 19:12:47.896 DEBUG 175 ---
> [io-20656-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured
> GET /?v-r=init&location=create_account&query= 2023-04-15 19:12:47.897
> DEBUG 175 --- [io-20656-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
> : GET
> "/BeersAndMealsAppFrontendDebug/?v-r=init&location=create_account&query=",
> parameters={masked} 2023-04-15 19:12:47.899 DEBUG 175 ---
> [io-20656-exec-3] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not
> store anonymous SecurityContext 2023-04-15 19:12:47.899 DEBUG 175 ---
> [io-20656-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed
> 200 OK 2023-04-15 19:12:47.900 DEBUG 175 --- [io-20656-exec-3]
> w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store anonymous
> SecurityContext 2023-04-15 19:12:47.900 DEBUG 175 ---
> [io-20656-exec-3] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared
> SecurityContextHolder to complete request 2023-04-15 19:12:48.073
> DEBUG 175 --- [io-20656-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy
> : Securing POST /?v-r=uidl&v-uiId=4 2023-04-15 19:12:48.073 DEBUG 175
> --- [io-20656-exec-5] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext 2023-04-15 19:12:48.073
> DEBUG 175 --- [io-20656-exec-5]
> o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder
> to anonymous SecurityContext 2023-04-15 19:12:48.073 DEBUG 175 ---
> [io-20656-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    :
> Authorized filter invocation [POST /?v-r=uidl&v-uiId=4] with
> attributes [permitAll] 2023-04-15 19:12:48.073 DEBUG 175 ---
> [io-20656-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured
> POST /?v-r=uidl&v-uiId=4 2023-04-15 19:12:48.073 DEBUG 175 ---
> [io-20656-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST
> "/BeersAndMealsAppFrontendDebug/?v-r=uidl&v-uiId=4",
> parameters={masked} 2023-04-15 19:12:48.075 DEBUG 175 ---
> [io-20656-exec-5] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     :
> Autowiring by type from bean name
> 'com.cokroktosmok.beersandmealsappfront.view.CreateAccountForm' via
> constructor to bean named 'backendCommunicationClient' 2023-04-15
> 19:12:48.075 DEBUG 175 --- [io-20656-exec-5]
> o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Autowiring by type from
> bean name
> 'com.cokroktosmok.beersandmealsappfront.view.CreateAccountForm' via
> constructor to bean named 'createdUserDto' 2023-04-15 19:12:48.079
> DEBUG 175 --- [io-20656-exec-5] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate
> : HTTP GET
> http://maluch.mikr.us:20656/BeersAndMealsAppBackendDebug/user/login_validator?login=
> 2023-04-15 19:12:48.080 DEBUG 175 --- [io-20656-exec-5]
> o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Accept=[application/json,
> application/*+json] 2023-04-15 19:14:58.576 DEBUG 175 ---
> [io-20656-exec-5] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not
> store anonymous SecurityContext 2023-04-15 19:14:58.577 DEBUG 175 ---
> [io-20656-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed
> 200 OK 2023-04-15 19:14:58.577 DEBUG 175 --- [io-20656-exec-5]
> w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store anonymous
> SecurityContext 2023-04-15 19:14:58.577 DEBUG 175 ---
> [io-20656-exec-5] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared
> SecurityContextHolder to complete request 2023-04-15 19:14:58.698
> DEBUG 175 --- [io-20656-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy
> : Securing POST /?v-r=uidl&v-uiId=4 2023-04-15 19:14:58.698 DEBUG 175
> --- [io-20656-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext 2023-04-15 19:14:58.698
> DEBUG 175 --- [io-20656-exec-1]
> o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder
> to anonymous SecurityContext 2023-04-15 19:14:58.698 DEBUG 175 ---
> [io-20656-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    :
> Authorized filter invocation [POST /?v-r=uidl&v-uiId=4] with
> attributes [permitAll] 2023-04-15 19:14:58.698 DEBUG 175 ---
> [io-20656-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured
> POST /?v-r=uidl&v-uiId=4 2023-04-15 19:14:58.698 DEBUG 175 ---
> [io-20656-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST
> "/BeersAndMealsAppFrontendDebug/?v-r=uidl&v-uiId=4",
> parameters={masked} 2023-04-15 19:14:58.700 DEBUG 175 ---
> [io-20656-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not
> store anonymous SecurityContext 2023-04-15 19:14:58.700 DEBUG 175 ---
> [io-20656-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed
> 200 OK 2023-04-15 19:14:58.700 DEBUG 175 --- [io-20656-exec-1]
> w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store anonymous
> SecurityContext 2023-04-15 19:14:58.700 DEBUG 175 ---
> [io-20656-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared
> SecurityContextHolder to complete request 2023-04-15 19:14:58.731
> DEBUG 175 --- [io-20656-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy
> : Securing GET
> /VAADIN/dynamic/resource/4/7d9b172b-29b9-4201-acb1-15a416862d95/logo.png
> 2023-04-15 19:14:58.731 DEBUG 175 --- [io-20656-exec-2]
> s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder
> to empty SecurityContext 2023-04-15 19:14:58.731 DEBUG 175 ---
> [io-20656-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set
> SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext 2023-04-15
> 19:14:58.732 DEBUG 175 --- [io-20656-exec-2]
> o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorized filter
> invocation [GET
> /VAADIN/dynamic/resource/4/7d9b172b-29b9-4201-acb1-15a416862d95/logo.png]
> with attributes [permitAll] 2023-04-15 19:14:58.732 DEBUG 175 ---
> [io-20656-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured
> GET
> /VAADIN/dynamic/resource/4/7d9b172b-29b9-4201-acb1-15a416862d95/logo.png
> 2023-04-15 19:14:58.732 DEBUG 175 --- [io-20656-exec-2]
> o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET
> "/BeersAndMealsAppFrontendDebug/VAADIN/dynamic/resource/4/7d9b172b-29b9-4201-acb1-15a416862d95/logo.png",
> parameters={} 2023-04-15 19:14:58.747 DEBUG 175 --- [io-20656-exec-2]
> w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store anonymous
> SecurityContext 2023-04-15 19:14:58.884 DEBUG 175 ---
> [io-20656-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed
> 200 OK 2023-04-15 19:14:58.884 DEBUG 175 --- [io-20656-exec-2]
> w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Did not store anonymous
> SecurityContext 2023-04-15 19:14:58.884 DEBUG 175 ---
> [io-20656-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared
> SecurityContextHolder to complete request

I have added a small popup to my frontend that checks the response code from my backend, and it gives a "500 Internal Server Error". However, as you can see, there is nothing in catalina.out, even though the logs are configured to be at the INFO level. From a user perspective, after I try to access the functionality that requires communication with my backend, the page gets stuck on loading, and after a few minutes, the "failsafe" kicks in (coded in case the response codes from the backend are not 200). From my perspective, it looks like some sort of timeouts, but as stated before, there is nothing in catalina.out.

2. The second problem is somewhat related to the first one. I've configured the domain, Cloudflare, and Nginx to redirect communication to my Tomcat. I know that DNS and Cloudflare are configured properly because the VPS has a dummy server setup on it, and my domain successfully redirects to it without Nginx. The problem starts when I'm trying to redirect traffic to my Tomcat using reverse proxy. When trying to access the page, I'm getting a 504 on my web browser, and Nginx saves error logs like this:

> 2023/04/15 19:27:46 [error] 180#180: *5 upstream timed out (110:
> Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client:
> 2400:cb00:632:1024::6ca2:e2e5, server: 2a01:4f9:6a:18a8::656, request:
> "GET /cms/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml HTTP/1.1", upstream:
> "http://65.21.225.215:20656/BeersAndMealsAppFullV2/cms/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml", host: "beersandmeals.xyz" 2023/04/15 19:28:14 [error] 180#180: *22
> upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to
> upstream, client: 2400:cb00:12:1024::ac45:217f, server:
> 2a01:4f9:6a:18a8::656, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream:
> "http://65.21.225.215:20656/BeersAndMealsAppFullV2/", host:
> "beersandmeals.xyz" 2023/04/15 19:28:46 [error] 180#180: *5 upstream
> timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream,
> client: 2400:cb00:632:1024::6ca2:e2e5, server: 2a01:4f9:6a:18a8::656,
> request: "GET /sito/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml HTTP/1.1", upstream:
> "http://65.21.225.215:20656/BeersAndMealsAppFullV2/sito/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml", host: "beersandmeals.xyz" 2023/04/15 19:29:14 [error] 180#180: *22
> upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while connecting to
> upstream, client: 2400:cb00:12:1024::ac45:217f, server:
> 2a01:4f9:6a:18a8::656, request: "GET /blog/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml
> HTTP/1.1", upstream:
> "http://65.21.225.215:20656/BeersAndMealsAppFullV2/blog/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml", host: "beersandmeals.xyz"

For me, both problems are related and connected to something restricting the connection between apps or accessing them, and it also feel like it must be tomcat/VPS related, but after a week of trying, I still can't pinpoint the problem.

What I tried:

1. Fresh installation of everything.
2. Testing multiple versions of Tomcat.
3. Testing multiple browsers.
4. Changing the levels of the catalina.out logs in the hope that there will be some sort of error.
5. Checking firewall settings.
6. Giving tomcat user root status.
7. I have also briefly talked with a senior DevOps, and he suggested dropping Tomcat for something more modern, but if it's VPS related, then it would be just a massive waste of time.

Comment: If there is any more information I can provide, just tell.

Comment: I know that post is dead, but I tried to add additional configuration to spring security, related to CORS, but it didnt helped.